# Xamarin - what happens when special characters not available on device?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts

According to [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts),

> Xamarin.Forms uses a system font defined by each platform.

My app uses [label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/label) to display text which contains special characters like: ∫, Δ, θ, ∠,...

I've tested on my device and saw that the special characters are rendered properly, but I can't predict what will happen when these special characters not available on other devices, e.g assume one of my users has an Android device that can't render the character "∫", when the label tries to render the text "Ha Ha ∫!!!", what will happen: A. It will display "Ha Ha ?!!!" or B. It will crash the app?

I'm afraid that case B may happens, so if it does, I may consider to use pronounce instead of symbol (e.g "integral" instead of "∫") to play it safe. If the worst scenario is case A, then I'll use the symbol to make it easy to understand for the user.

Comment: it's not going to crash the app.  Worst case is it will display some unknown glyph instead of the character you want.

Comment: @Jason - Thanks, I think that too, but I can't think of a special character that can prove that on my device.

Comment: Then this seems like a really weird problem to worry about.

Comment: @Jason - I want to test what will happens when it actually happens by put a special character that not available on my Android device. You know, my science instinct Murphy law :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out, it will display the rectangle.

I set the text of the label to `"Ha ha \U0007FFFF!!!"` and it displays like this "Ha ha **[rectangle]**!!!" (tested as WPF app):

[image: XamarinSpecialCharacter.jpg]